# Size of the table in excel to be based on the value of a specified cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So i am not a coder but i do use excel and understand certain codes.
I wanted to know if it is possible to create a table whose size in particular depends upon the value given in a or two cell(s).

For example refer the image:
[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGiaE.png)

So in this particular case, i need that the when i change the value in F2 or F6 (which ever is possible) to lets say, 8 then the number of rows in first table should increase to 8 but while doing so it shall push down the table 2 i.e it should not effect the content of table 2.

Is that possible? Help needed.

Comment: To answer your question - yes. This isn't code-writing service, people get help here with the code they've already came up with, so I will only give a few hints. Use `Worksheet_Change` Sub to detect changing of cells on a `Worksheet`(Alt+F11, Microsoft_Excel_Objects -> Worksheet you need (double click) -> from *General* to *Worksheet* -> from *Declarations* to *Change*), to check for changes in particular range I prefer using `Intersect` method, after that you need to compare number of rows in your table and the number in the cell, value of which you've changed and do stuff accordingly.

Comment: The basic steps would include: FInd the location of your first table using Range("Table2[#All]").Address  (use the name of your table), extract the last row of the address with Split function, insert the x rows you have stated in the cell, at row number last row  +1  , resize your table with syntax like ListObjects("Table2").Resize Range("$A$1:$C$8") using your table name and substituting the final 8 with 8 + additional number of rows. Record a macro doing the insert rows step and table resize on your table to get an idea of how this example relates to your data.

Comment: @AntiDrondert After a little bit of surfing, now i really get to know that this platform is about learning and not getting your work done by others. So i'll take a lead with your hint and the next time i'll ask a question it would be code wise. :)